# How can I solve this express node ejs problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hello guys please I am new to node.js.I keep getting this error.Please can someone explain to me.

```
Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%=".
    at /Users//Desktop/Web Development/getting_started_express js/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:727:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Template.generateSource (/Users//Desktop/Web Development/getting_started_express js/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:717:15)
    at Template.compile (/Users//Desktop/Web Development/getting_started_express js/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:571:12)
    at Object.compile (/Users//Desktop/Web Development/getting_started_express js/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:385:16)
    at handleCache (/Users//Desktop/Web Development/getting_started_express js/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:233:18)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users//Desktop/Web Development/getting_started_express js/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users//Desktop/Web Development/getting_started_express js/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:478:10)
    at View.render (/Users//Desktop/Web Development/getting_started_express js/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users//Desktop/Web Development/getting_started_express js/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
```

even after deleting ejs module and installing it again. as well as deleting my ejs file from view folder and creating a new ejs file. this time without using the "<%=" code, but yet I still get this error.

```
const express = require ('express');
const path = require ('path');
const ejs = require ('ejs');
const app = express();

app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'views')));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('index') //,{data : {userQuery: req.params.userQuery,
                              //searchResults : ['book1','book2','book3']}});
  //we can optionally pass a data in render
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Here is the EJS template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>You Searched For: <%= data.userQuery %> </h1>
    <ul>
      <li>data</li>
    </ul>`

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It means there's no closing tag for the opening `<%= ...` Most likely in one of your EJS files. Which we can't see.

Comment: Opening a `<%=` tag requires you to close it with `%> `if you're using EJS.

Comment: @DaveNewton  I deleted all my EJS files.I then used a basic html file with an EJS extension and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Newbie123 I did exactly that but still getting same error.

Comment: Why are you giving the HTML file an EJS extension if you're not using EJS? Check your previous code for any missing close tags, if you're still struggling please post it on SO so we can have a look. NOTE: If you have multiple EJS files, the missing tag may not be in the one you think may contain the error so check thoroughly.

Comment: We have no way of knowing without being able to see anything of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In EJS, the syntax goes as
`<p> X is <%= data.x %> </p>`
The shown error just means you have a `<%=` and no closing `%>` to match it. I would suggest searching your .ejs files for these and using search tools to track the missing one down.

Comment: I did. check it out.<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>You Searched For: <%= data.userQuery %> </h1>
    <!-- to output on browser page, use <%= followed by data you passed in your js. -->
    <ul>
      <li>dummy data</li>
      <!-- <% data.searchResults.forEach(result=>{ %>
        <li> <%= result %> </li>
      <% }) %> -->
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>

Comment: @Doe And there's the problem--EJS doesn't care about HTML comments.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have now deleted all comments and all EJS syntax (<%= %>) but yet still I am getting the same error. Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%=". I now have a pure html file but still the tag error keep appearing. I have uninstall and reinstall EJS again but the error keep appearing even with pure HTML (as EJS template of course).

Comment: @Doe This is unlikely--it's more likely the code you think is being executed isn't.

Comment: @DaveNewton so do you think it as to do with res.render?

Answer (score 0):

This is the line of code giving you the error: `<!-- to output on the browser page, use <%= followed by data you passed in your js. -->`

EJS doesn't care about HTML comments. EJS processes only EJS syntax, so from the EJS processor's standpoint you're missing the closing `%>` for the opening `<%=` contained in the HTML comment. HTML comments are only relevant to the browser.

You can create an EJS comment using `<%# comment %>` ([documentation](http://ejs.co/)).

You can also have multi-line comments using `<% /* */ %>`,

Original code you posted as a comment for @theParadox42 answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>search</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>You Searched For: <%= data.userQuery %> </h1>
  <!-- to output on browser page, use <%= followed by data you passed in your js. 
  --> 
  <ul> 
  <li>dummy data</li> 
  <!-- <% data.searchResults.forEach(result=>{ %> <li> <%= result %> </li> <% }) %> --> 
  </ul> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: @DaveNewton,@theParadox42,@Newbie123.I thank you a lot for your time and patience.Now all I need is to figured the file out and then indent my code well.

Comment: @theParadox42 it is working now.All I did was to delete my entire views folder and recreate it.Then I made sure to not add any comment. and boom it is working like a boss. Thank you guys.